# putting two different legends in two columns in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following reproducible code which gets me the plot listed below:

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
ChickWt <- data.frame(ChickWeight, AR = sample(c("p=0", "p=1", "hat(p)"), size = 578, replace = T))

exprvec <- expression( p==hat(p), p==0, p==1)
p1 <-  ggplot(ChickWt, aes(x=Time, y=weight, colour=Diet, Group = Chick, linetype = AR)) + geom_line()
p1 <- p1 + scale_linetype_manual(values=c(2,4,1), labels = exprvec,name="AR order") + theme_bw() + theme(legend.justification=c(1,-0.2), legend.position=c(0.3,0.2), legend.text=element_text(size=10), legend.title=element_text(size=10), axis.title.x=element_text(size=10), axis.title.y=element_text(size = 10), legend.key = element_blank(), legend.background = element_rect(color="black",size = 0.1)) + ylim(c(0,400)) + guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2))
```

[image]

but I would like the legend on Diet and AR order in two separate columns. How do I get this to work? Clearly, the `guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2))` has no effect, perhaps because these are two separate legends.

Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that `guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2))` does not work is because it only refers to the `fill`-legend and not to the `linetype`-legend. You can position the legends next to each other by using `legend.box = "horizontal"`:

```
ggplot(ChickWt, aes(x=Time, y=weight, colour=Diet, Group = Chick, linetype = AR)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(2,4,1), labels = exprvec,name="AR order") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.justification=c(1,-0.2),
        legend.position=c(0.3,0.2),
        legend.text=element_text(size=10),
        legend.title=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size = 10),
        legend.key = element_blank(),
        legend.background = element_rect(color="black",size = 0.1),
        legend.box = "horizontal") + 
  ylim(c(0,400))
```

which gives:

[image]